# Codegen generates graphql schema with import in incorrect place

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen

I am using the [graphql code generator](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen) tool to generate graphql types and hooks, and for some reason it generates a schema.ts file where the following import is placed all the way down on line 197 rather than at the top:

```
import { IntrospectionQuery } from 'graphql';
```

Thus react obviously complains with:

```
src/graphql/generated/schema.ts
  Line 197:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
```

Here is the part of the schema.ts file:

```
…

export type SendEmMutation = { __typename?: 'Mutation', sendPasswordResetEmail: { __typename?: 'SuccessResponse', success: boolean } };

import { IntrospectionQuery } from 'graphql';
export default {
  "__schema": {
    "queryType": {
      "name": "Query"
    },
    "mutationType": {

…
```

The codegen.yml file:

```
overwrite: true
schema: ${GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT}
documents: '**/*.{gql,graphql}'
generates:
    src/graphql/generated/schema.ts:
        plugins:
            - 'typescript'
            - 'typescript-operations'
            - 'urql-introspection'
            - 'typescript-urql'
        config:
            withHooks: true
    ./graphql.schema.json:
        plugins:
            - 'introspection'
```

Package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "2.11.8",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "2.2.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "2.7.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "2.5.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-urql": "^3.6.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/urql-introspection": "2.2.1",
```

The script `npm run codegen` generates the file by running this (in scripts in package.json) "graphql-codegen --require dotenv/config"

I can of course just manually remove the import from line 197 and place it at the top; but why is it adding the import around line 197? I'd rather not have to manually do this every time I run the `npm run codegen` script. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Note that I am using URQL client at the front-end and Apollo Server at the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Charly, from The Guild, working on GraphQL Code Generator.

You are right; the output of the `urql-introspection` plugin could be considered as invalid for some linters.

However, please know that we recommend not committing and excluding from code formatters (ex: Prettier) and linters all the files generated by codegen.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Charly. I ended up removing urql-introspection and it is no longer an issue